# Windows phone 8, button that opens URL in web browser

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser

How do I link a button to url, so that when the button is pressed, it opens a web browser and goes to specific URL? (Windows phone 8). using windows phone silverlight 8

Answer (score 4):

It's super simple!

```
WebBrowserTask namewhatevz = new WebBrowserTask();
namewhatevz.Uri = new uri("http://google.se", UriKind.Absolute);
namewhatevz.Show();
```

**Regards!**

Bachir Bouchemla

Answer (score 0):

Just register a `Click` event on your button and in the event handler use `LaunchUri`:

To do so, go to your .xaml and edit your Button.

```
<Button x:Name="LinkButton" Click="Button_Click" Content="Click here" />
```

Your `Button` *LinkButton* now executes code behind function *Button_Click* when you click it.
Place the following function to code behind xaml.cs.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("www.google.com"));
}
```

Comment: I just got into visual studio 4 days ago, so i dont know much about it. can you tell me how to add a click event to the button? with just the text box i dont have a event handler called LaunchUri

Comment: when i try to send the app over to the device i get this: Error 1 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\new anon app\C#\TwitterSample\MainPage.xaml.cs 105 13 TwitterSample

Comment: Just a wild guess: You messed up the curly braces and put your `Button_Click`function inside another function or even outside of the `MainPage` class? - Whatever, please show your code. Maybe even in a new question regarding that specific issue.